# Python Group by first item in list and return Keys

Tags: python-2.7

I am able to group a list by its first item but I cannot figure out how to return the unique keys.

```
from itertools import groupby

List = [['Hello','Sam',27,5],['Hello','Mark',22,4],['Goodby','Steven',86,34]]

keys = []

glist = [list(item[1])for item in groupby(sorted(List), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Comment: What do you mean by unique keys? What is your expected answer for this example?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = [['Hello','Sam',27,5],['Hello','Mark',22,4],['Goodby','Steven',86,34]]

for key, group in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    print(key + " :", list(group))

#output:
Hello : [['Hello', 'Sam', 27, 5], ['Hello', 'Mark', 22, 4]]
Goodby : [['Goodby', 'Steven', 86, 34]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved my problem.